# Profiler is always overwriting the CSV file to debug multiple subsequent requests

Tags: magento2, development, profiler

I have enabled the profiler in order to find out which events are triggered during order creation and processing.

```
php bin/magento dev:profiler:enable csvfile
```

But it is alway overwriting

```
var/log/profiler.csv
```

On each request.

How can I keep all profiler output across requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to output a request per file and you can not modify the vendor folder, you can extend in your own module the standard Csvfile class:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Output;

class Csvfile extends \Magento\Framework\Profiler\Driver\Standard\Output\Csvfile
{
    /**
     * Parses file path
     *
     * @param array|null $config
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _parseFilePath(array $config = null)
    {
        $result = parent::_parseFilePath($config);
        return str_replace('.csv', "-".date('Ymd-His')."-".uniqid('', true).".csv", $result);
    }
}
```

Then you can launch the profiler with:

```
php bin\magento dev:profiler:enable "\\Vendor\\Module\\Output\\Csvfile"
```

Now the profiler will output each request in a different `var/log/profile-yyyymmdd-hhmmss-rand.csv` file.

Answer (score 2):

A temporary are to change this is to edit this line:

```
vendor/magento/framework/Profiler/Driver/Standard/Output/Csvfile.php:41
```

To

```
public function __construct(array $config = null)
{
    parent::__construct($config);
    # change this line, append uniqid()
    $this->_filePath = $this->_parseFilePath($config) . uniqid('', true);
    $this->_delimiter = isset($config['delimiter']) ? $config['delimiter'] : ',';
    $this->_enclosure = isset($config['enclosure']) ? $config['enclosure'] : '"';
}
```

Of course this is a core patch and only for temporary use.